# Textbox not refreshing

Tags: vb.net, textbox, refresh

```
 Dim VoucherOpenConnection As New OleDbConnection
    ' VoucherOpenConnection = New OleDbConnection
    VoucherOpenConnection.ConnectionString = "My Connection String"

 Dim VoucherString As String = "My Query"

        Dim DAVoucherString As New OleDbDataAdapter(VoucherString, VoucherOpenConnection)
        Dim DTVoucherString As New DataTable

        DAVoucherString.Fill(DTVoucherString)

        If DTVoucherString.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            cmbCategory.Text = DTVoucherString.Rows(0).Item(8).ToString
            txtDetails.Text = DTVoucherString.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
            txtshop.Text = DTVoucherString.Rows(0).Item(3).ToString
            txtAmount.Text = DTVoucherString.Rows(0).Item(4).ToString
            txtRemarks.Text = DTVoucherString.Rows(0).Item(5).ToString
            txtInvoiceNum.Text = DTVoucherString.Rows(0).Item(11).ToString
            txtCashAmt.Text = DTVoucherString.Rows(0).Item(6).ToString
            Me.Refresh()
        Else
            MsgBox("No valid record could be found(Cash)!!")
        End If
```

I have the above code inside a sub procedure and call it from another form. When the sub is called the first time, all the textboxes display the correct values. But when I try again, the values do not update. Putting a breakpoint in the sub reveals that the code is working correctly as hovering the mouse over the textboxes shows the correct values.
I have already tried the following methods to no avail:
`Me.Refresh`
`Me.Update`
`Textbox.update/refresh`

This is in VB.NET 2019.

Edit:Code in the calling form:

```
  Private Sub DGVTotalReport_CellMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As 
   DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles 
   DGVTotalReport.CellMouseDoubleClick

    Dim ExpForm As New ExpenseEntry
    My.Settings.TranCodeExpOpen = 
    DGVTotalReport.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).Value


    If My.Settings.ExpenseForm = False Then
        ExpForm.Show()
        ExpForm.OpenVoucher()
        My.Settings.ExpenseForm = True


    Else           
        My.Settings.ExpenseForm = True

        ExpForm.Activate()
        ExpForm.OpenVoucher()
        ExpForm.Refresh()


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you simply load same values. What you need to do before this code is clear text boxes. Then you will know if values are fully reloaded and no msgbox appears, then you know that values are the same

Comment: Have you actually debugged the code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through the code line by line and examined the state before and after each step? If not, it's too soon to be posting here. If so, you need to tell us what you saw.

Comment: Maybe you have created a new instance of an opened Form as a way to access its properties/controls (do you have `...New SomeForm()` somewhere?). -- Unrelated: I'd suggest to use DataBindings, but it's not clear what this procedure is supposed to do; i.e., if the query should fetch a single record (where the connection object is coming from is also undefined).

Comment: Please read my post again. I have mentioned the breakpoint. Putting the breakpoint anywhere(in the sub) reveals the state of the textboxes and as I said, hovering the mouse shows that the textbox is getting the correct data but simply not refreshing on the form. As per @T.S.suggestion I also tried to first blank all the textboxes but the problem remains.

Comment: @Jimi I have updated the code in my post. Thank You.

Comment: What you want to do is to create a new instance of `ExpenseEntry` only when one doesn't currently exist. `My.Settings.ExpenseForm` is useless here (I suppose you also set it when `ExpenseEntry` closes), because you create a new instance in any case. You can use the `Application.OpenForms` collection for that.

Comment: Ok @Jimi I got what you are saying. Every time I run that sub, a new instance of the form is being created and that may be causing that issue. While I tried to search on the internet, I could not find a solution to use `Application.Openforms` to use in this particular situation because VB.NET2019 demands I create a new instance of the form to access the sub procedure. I would appreciate it if you could give me a code block to resolve this. You are also right in that I set the settings variable to False on form closing event Thank You.